# Possible to get SecureCRT to show windows, not tabs, in Windows taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, tabs, securecrt

Upgrading SecureCRT from version 5.2 to 6.3, the behavior of the application in the Windows 7 taskbar changed so that clicking on the application icon brings up a list of each individual tab that is open, rather than a list of the windows that are open. As I keep a very large number of SCRT tabs open, this is horrible. Is there a way to get back the behavior of 5.2, where the taskbar brought up windows, not tabs?

Answer (score 2):

The article [SecureCRT 6.5 and Windows 7 Taskbar](https://forums.vandyke.com/showpost.php?p=21177&postcount=21) may relate to this problem :

> To disable Aero Peek functionality within SecureCRT, follow these
>   steps (assuming you're running SecureCRT 6.5 Official release or
>   later):
>
> Browse to the location of the SecureCRT configuration folder as
>   displayed in Global Options, General, Configuration folder.
>
> Close all instances of SecureCRT (and SecureFX, if you're running both
>   apps on the same system with an integrated configuration).
>
> Edit the Global.ini file and change the following line From:
>
> ```
>     D:"Disable Aero Peek"=00000000
> ```
>
> To:
>
> ```
>     D:"Disable Aero Peek"=00000001
> ```
>
> Save your changes to the Global.ini file and start SecureCRT.